# SAPUI5 - Content is not displayed

Tags: sapui5

experts,

I've just started to study sapui5, and right now the thing that bothers me is that I can't get a dropdown menu to be shown, while a button I create together with the drop down menu is displayed.

Here is my view:

```js
createContent : function(oController) {

        var aControls = [];

        var oButton = new sap.ui.commons.Button({
            id : this.createId("MyButton"),
            text : "Get response from servlet"
        });
        oButton.attachPress(oController.getResponse);
        aControls.push(oButton);

        $.ajax({
            url : "GetEmployees",
            type : "post",
            success : function(response) {

                var oEmployeeSelection = new sap.ui.commons.DropdownBox("employee");
                oEmployeeSelection.setTooltip("Employee");
                oEmployeeSelection.setWidth("300px");

                $.each(response, function(index, employee) {
                alert("entered selection creation");
                var oItem = new sap.ui.core.ListItem("Employee"+index);
                oItem.setText(employee);
                oEmployeeSelection.addItem(oItem);
                alert("processed: "+oItem);
                });
                alert(oEmployeeSelection);
                // Attach the DropdownBox to the page
                aControls.push(oEmployeeSelection);


            }, // end success call handler

            error: function(){
                alert("error while building employee select menu");
            }
        });// end Employee selection

        return aControls;

    }// end createContent
```

I do get data from the server, alerts inside the success function shoot, but I see only the button on screen.
What an I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The root cause is that you add the Dropdown box in the service callback method and the aControls is already returned with only oButton inserted before the service callback.

Adjust the code as following will do:

```js
createContent: function(oController) {

        var aControls = [];

        var oButton = new sap.ui.commons.Button({
            id: this.createId("MyButton"),
            text: "Get response from servlet"
        });
        oButton.attachPress(oController.getResponse);
        aControls.push(oButton);

        //Add dropdown box before your service call

        var oEmployeeSelection = new sap.ui.commons.DropdownBox("employee");
        oEmployeeSelection.setTooltip("Employee");
        oEmployeeSelection.setWidth("300px");
        aControls.push(oEmployeeSelection);

        $.ajax({
            url: "GetEmployees",
            type: "post",
            success: function(response) {
                $.each(response, function(index, employee) {
                    alert("entered selection creation");
                    var oItem = new sap.ui.core.ListItem("Employee" + index);
                    oItem.setText(employee);
                    oEmployeeSelection.addItem(oItem);
                    alert("processed: " + oItem);
                });
                alert(oEmployeeSelection);

            }, // end success call handler

            error: function() {
                alert("error while building employee select menu");
            }
        }); // end Employee selection

        return aControls;

    } // end createContent
```

Comment: Your suggestion worked pretty well - now I see both drop down menu and the datepicker. Thank you! But now they are positioned one right after another. How do I position them in the view?

Comment: use a layout like SimpleForm. Add your controls to the SimpleForm, then return it rather than a simple array of controls.